# Store data for later reuse in Greasemonkey

Tags: spam-prevention, greasemonkey, jquery

I would like to add a remove/blacklist button next to all links in the Blogspot statistics. Some of them are referrer spam, and I would like to remove them forever. So far I'm selecting them using this kind of jQuery selector:

```
$('a[href*="referer.spam.domain"]').closest("li").hide();
```

but I would like it to be more flexible, because I have to manually edit the script for each new domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store data for later reuse, you would use [the GM_setValue function](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue) as well as [GM_getValue()](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_getValue).
These two functions have the unique advantage that they store data across multiple domains.  Now that `globalStorage` is obsolete, they are the only method to do that.

Or you could also use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage) or cookies, but these may not allow for what you want because they only work for one domain at a time.

If you try `GM_setValue()`, you'll probably need to do it by using [the `GM_SuperValue` utilities](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/107941) instead, since `GM_setValue()`, by itself, does not do a good job of storing anything but strings.

---

***However,*** in this particular case, adding a line to the script for each site might be better because:

1. If your example is typical, it is only one new line per site (not counting any site-specific `@include` directives).
2. You need to store *code* as well as data.
   For example, in the question, you are using not only the *selector* (`'a[href*="referer.spam.domain"]'`), but also the *relationship* (`.closest("li")`). Both of these would presumably have to be stored.
   Storing this is a new level of complexity that is probably not warranted in this case.
3. It's not as simple as just "storing data".  You will also need ways to: Add, List, Edit and Delete values.  That's a lot more code if you want to do it right. But you can use utilities like ["Script Options Dialog"](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/115197) to help with the user interface.